# Is there any command line tool that can be used to edit environment variables in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, environment-variables

Is there any command line tool that can be used to edit environment variables in Windows?

It would be nice if this was smart tool, for example:

- When adding some path to let's say the PATH variable and this path is already there it shouldn't double this entry.
- Inserting a new path to the PATH variable should be possible before/after some other path or in specific order (the first, the 7th, the last etc.).
- It should be possible to change only part of variable's value (in case of the PATH a given path from a list of all paths).

And the last but not the least - **I want my changes to persist between sessions** so simple SET is out of question...

There's very nice GUI tool for this called [Path Editor](http://www.redfernplace.com/software-projects/patheditor) and I need something like this but for command line.

Comment: Technically, yes. It's called SET. I know it's not pretty, but you can't get much more straightforward than just setting the variables with the tools at hand.

Comment: Interesting. I thought for sure there would be a fairly well-known third-party tool for this.

Comment: What version of Windows are you running?

Comment: @musicfreak Vista Home Premium 64bit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Path Manager (pathman.exe) from Windows Server 2003 Resource Kit Tools is the closest match I could find. It was already available in NT Resource Kit.

Comment: maybe try `setx.exe`

Comment: @n611x007, `setx` is for general environment variables; `pathman` is specifically for manipulating (i.e., **parsing**) the path.

Answer (score 17):

I don't know any tool that does this, but maybe you can use the `reg`command:

```
reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path
```

to read the current path, and

```
reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v Path /d "newPath" /f
```

to write your new value.

You need admin rights for hsving right acccess in HKLM. If that is a problem, consider modifying the user specific path setting in  `HKCU\Environment` instead.

Comment: This answer should have been accepted, it can change any environement variable and can even be encapsulated in a batch file so one only needs to enter the name and the new value.

Comment: If this is combined with Vi, it'd come closer to meeting the questioner's criteria. e.g. a batch file that writes the path to a temporary text file, opens it in vi, then when you close vi it writes the file to the path. That way you can easily edit your path via command line. I did something like that in XP, with a batch file, notepad and those reg commands.

Comment: WARNING do NOT copy-paste this mindlessly unless you want to do something silly...

Comment: This approach would take a system restart to apply. The OS is not aware this value is changed (without triggering WM_SETTINGSCHANGE message). To avoid a reboot, use a tool similar to EnvUpdate of AutoHotkey https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/EnvUpdate.htm, or use setx command to set and unset some unimportant value after setting the registry value (setx tool has its own limitations, so a combination of both may be better in some cases)

Answer (score 7):

If you need a generic way to set any environment variable and have the changes persist, then [setx.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=DC2D3339-8F36-4FBA-A406-2A2A2AD7208C&displaylang=en) would be the tool to use.  It cannot do the "smart" things you are asking for, though...

setx.exe is included with Windows Vista or later; if you use an earlier version of Windows, you can use the above download link to get it.

Answer (score 5):

For the current program, there is `path`:

> Displays or sets a search path for executable files.
>
> ```
> PATH [[drive:]path[;...][;%PATH%]
> PATH ;
> ```
>
> Type `PATH ;` to clear all search-path settings and direct `cmd.exe` to search only in the current directory.
>
> Type `PATH` without parameters to display the current path.
>   Including `%PATH%` in the new path setting causes the old path to be
>   appended to the new setting.

However, this is pretty much the same as `set PATH`.

For environment variables to persist you have to edit the registry or use `setx`.

Answer (score 3):

I just discovered the ability to allow the users to run the Environment Variables edit dialog without elevated privileges.

From the Start menu, run the following:

```
rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables
```

Comment: +1 for a command line way of getting to the GUI edit widget, because that's certainly more straight forward than the click path, even though the answer is off-topic because Q is about editing PATH from command line.

Answer (score 3):

You might wanna check out pathed of the gtools collection:
http://www.p-nand-q.com/gtools.html

It provides a set of commands for the command promt like

```
pathed /APPEND %CD% /USER
```

to append the current path for example. I haven't really checked it out to be honest, as I'm totally fine with using a GUI.

Other options are:

```
  /MACHINE: print machine PATH
     /USER: print user PATH
      /ADD: add variable at the head
   /APPEND: add variable at the tail
   /REMOVE: remove path / index
     /SLIM: strip duplicate vars
      /ENV: environment variable, defaults to PATH
```

Together with which of the same collection, you got yourself some good tools, I suppose. Which  "locates executable files on the PATH".

```
 /EXTENSION: search for extension , can be a ; separated list
       /DIR: add directory , can be a ; separated list
 /RECURSIVE: search directories recursively
    /SINGLE: stop after the first find result
       /ENV: environment variable, defaults to PATH
FILE {FILE}: one or more files to find
```

Source: http://op111.net/82/

Comment: Can you explain what you're linking to?  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked content becomes unavailable.

Comment: Shure. Sorry i was implictly refering to the question.

Comment: Seems the URL for Gtools and pathed is now dead.  http://www.p-nand-q.com/gtools.html

Answer (score 2):

set PATH

(help set)

Comment: this is only for the terminal session, and to add/change values you need to retype the entire old path as well.

Comment: Not true. SET PATH=%path%;c:\newpath

Comment: you still typed it, just unexpanded :) That also won't save, try exiting the command prompt and opening a new one then check your path.

Comment: He didn't specify whether it needed to persist between sessions.

Comment: Well if you checked out what patheditor (his suggestion) does, it saves it permanently. set PATH is only really used in build scripts for programs because it is temporary.

Comment: in the Windows 2000 Resource Kit, I think Microsoft shipped a tool called setx.exe.  It works like the built-in set, but it applies permanently.  Not sure where to get setx.exe now, but it still works on vista.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a set of batch scripts for this.  addpath.bat adds elements to the path, rmpath.bat  removes elements from the path, and lpath.bat just lists the path. But then I needed some support scripts, so there is also chkpath.bat .

It ended up being not trivial and required tr.exe and cat.exe, a couple of unix-style utilities.  The reason its not trivial:  no backticks in cmd.exe (though you can use for loops for this), and short names versus long names.

addpath.bat:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set cwd=%~dps0

goto testit

:loopy

call %cwd%chkpath "%~1"
if %errorlevel%==2 (
  set path=%path%;%~1
)

shift

:testit
if not _%1==_ goto loopy


call %cwd%lpath.bat

endlocal & set path=%path%
```

ChkPath.bat:

```
@echo off
goto START

-------------------------------------------------------
chkpath.bat

checks path for existence of the given segment.
Returns 1 if present, 2 if not present, 0 if not checked.

The matching and checking complicated by case sensitivity and "short pathnames".

created sometime in 2003 and lovingly maintained since then.


-------------------------------------------------------

:START
setlocal enabledelayedExpansion
set rc=0
set cwd=%~dps0
set curdrive=%~d0
set tr=%curdrive%\bin\tr.exe
set regexe=%windir%\system32\reg.exe


if _%1==_ goto Usage


@REM convert arg 1 to a fully-qualified, short path name,
@REM and then convert to uppercase.
set toupper=%~fs1
call :ToUpper
set tocheck=%toupper%


if not _%TEMP%==_ goto GotTemp
call :gettemp


:GotTemp
set d=%DATE:~4%
set stamp=%d:~6%%d:~3,2%%d:~0,2%%TIME::=%
set d=
set tempfile1=%TEMP%\chkpath1-%stamp%.tmp

echo %path% | %tr% ; \n  >  %tempfile1%

@REM check each element in the path for the match:
for /f  "delims=^" %%I in (%tempfile1%) do (
  if !rc!==0 (
call :CheckElt "%%I"
  )
)

if %rc%==0 set rc=2
goto END


--------------------------------------------
* checkelt
*
* check one element in the path to see if it is the same
* as the TOCHECK string. The element is first canonicalized.
*

:CheckElt
@REM remove surrounding quotes
set ERF=%1
if [x%ERF%]==[x] goto CheckEltDone
@REM convert to fully-qualified, short paths, uppercase
set TOUPPER=%~fs1%
call :ToUpper
if _%TOCHECK% == _%TOUPPER% set rc=1
:CheckEltDone
goto:EOF
--------------------------------------------


--------------------------------------------
* backtick
*
* invoke a command and return the result as a string.
* This is like backtick in csh or bash.
* To call, set variable BACKTICK to the command to be run.
* The result will be stored in the env variable of the same name.
*

:backtick
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%i IN (`%backtick%`) DO (
  SET backtick=%%i
)
goto backtick_done
:backtick_none
  SET backtick=nothing to exec
:backtick_done
goto:EOF
--------------------------------------------


--------------------------------------------
* gettemp
*
* get the temporary directory, as stored in the registry.
* Relies on backtick.
*
* The result set TEMP.
*

:gettemp
set regkey=HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders
set regvalname=Local AppData
set backtick=%regexe% query "%regkey%" /v "%regvalname%"
call :backtick
for /f "tokens=4" %%a in ("%backtick%") do (
  set temp=%%a
)
goto:EOF
--------------------------------------------



--------------------------------------------
* ToUpper
*
* Convert a string to all uppercase.
* To call, set variable TOUPPER to the thing to be converted.
* The result will be stored in the env variable of the same name.
*

:ToUpper
  FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%I IN (`echo %toupper% ^| %tr% a-z A-Z`) DO (
SET toupper=%%I
  )
goto:EOF
--------------------------------------------


--------------------------------------------
:CleanUp
  if _%tempfile1%==_ goto CleanUpDone
  if exist %tempfile1% del %tempfile1%
  :CleanUpDone
goto:EOF
--------------------------------------------


--------------------------------------------
:Usage
echo.
echo Usage: chkpath ^<path^>
echo checks if path element is included in path variable.
echo returns 1 if yes, 2 if no, 0 if not checked.
echo.
goto END
--------------------------------------------


:END
call :CleanUp

:ReallyEnd

endlocal & set errorlevel=%rc%
@REM set errorlevel=%rc%
@REM echo %errorlevel%
```

lpath.bat:

```
@echo.
@set curdrive=%~d0

@REM This form post-fixes a | at the end of each path element. Useful for debugging trailing spaces.
@REM @path | %curdrive%\cygwin\bin\sed.exe -e s/PATH=// -e 's/;/^|\n/g' -e 's/$/^|/g'

@REM This form shows bare path elements.
@REM @path | %curdrive%\cygwin\bin\sed.exe -e 's/PATH=//' -e 's/;/^\n/g'
@path | %curdrive%\utils\sed -e "s/PATH=//" | %curdrive%\utils\tr ; \n
@echo.
```

Comment: I think the `for` loop could be used instead of `tr`/`cat` too.

Answer (score 1):

This is really easy, environment variables are stored in registry, specifically user environment variables are stored in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment`, system environment variables are stored in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`.

You don't need any third party software, you can achieve this I recommend you to use PowerShell, you can use `Get-ItemProperty` to query registry values and use `Set-ItemProperty` to modify registry values, `New-Item` to add registry keys, `Remove-Item` to delete registry keys and `Remove-ItemProperty` to delete registry values.

Now for example, to edit the `PATH` environment variable, you can use these:

If you want to edit the user `PATH`, you can use `$Env:PATH` to get its value;

Otherwise use `(Get-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" -Name PATH).PATH` to get value of system `PATH`.

Now this is a script example that modifies system `PATH`:

```powershell
$directory=Read-Host "Please input directory that needs to be added to PATH"
$path=(Get-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' -Name PATH).PATH.Split(';')
if ($directory -notin $path) {$path+=$directory}
$path=$path -join ";"
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' -Name PATH -Type String -Value $path
```

Save as a *.ps1 file and run it with PowerShell, it will add the directory you typed to `PATH` if it isn't already in `PATH`.

Answer (score 0):

[How to check if directory exists in %PATH%?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141344/how-to-check-if-directory-exists-in-path) on Stack Overflow has an [outstanding description](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8046515/14420) of what makes Windows PATH editing difficult along with a batch file to overcome them. Figuring out how to properly use `addpath.bat` took a bit of practice as it's calling structure was new to me, but this works:

```
set _path=C:\new\directory\to\add\to\path
call addpath.bat _path
set _path=
```

and repeated firings won't add the new directory if it's already present. This doesn't address making the edits persistent across sessions.

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is a late answer, but there is also EditPath.exe available in the release package for [PathMgr.dll](https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/PathMgr/).

EditPath.exe is a command-line tool you can use to update the system and user Path values in the registry. It can also test whether a directory exists in the system and user Path (determined by an exit code -- see the [documentation](https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/PathMgr/blob/master/EditPath.md)).

Alternatively, you can use [editenv](https://github.com/Bill-Stewart/editenv) if you want to interactively edit the value of an environment variable (such as Path) for the current process.