# Change environment variables as standard user

Tags: windows-7, environment-variables

When clicking on "Advanced system settings", I need to login as the administrator and hence only edit *the administrators environment variables* (in addition to the machine wide ones). **How do I edit the environment variables of a standard user?**

### Details

With the migration to Windows 7, I decided to work as a **standard user** instead of an unprivileged administrator. Works well so far but I encountered a tiny problem:

When I try to change per user environment variables via the control panel I have to login as an administrator.
But since I run that part of the control panel *as the administrator* I can only edit *the administrators variables*.

**How am I supposed to edit my own environment variables?** 
Without resorting to extreme measures, such as editing the registry (as suggested in ["Is there any command line tool that can be used to edit environment variables in Windows?"](https://superuser.com/questions/13783/is-there-any-command-line-tool-that-can-be-used-to-edit-environment-variables-in) )

Comment: Refer solution provided here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685699/windows-7-environment-variable-not-working-in-path/37507698#37507698 Quick tip: Use setx command

Answer (score 192, accepted):

Just type “environment” into the start menu (or press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> in Windows 10 and search for *“Edit environment variables for your account”*).

Similarly, searching for “environment” in the control panel yields that option, too.

Generally, I have noticed that simply searching for something in the start menu or control panel is much faster than trying to remember a series of icons, dialogs, etc. one has to access to find something. At least for the vast majority of tasks<sup>1</sup>.

A little digging yields that

```
rundll32 sysdm.cpl,EditEnvironmentVariables
```

is the command used to present that dialog. You can put a shortcut to that somewhere if you like.

---

<sup>1</sup> There are exceptions, such as installing a loopback network adapter. I looked for a few minutes before finally finding how to do that. But those things are hardly common scenarios :-)

Comment: Thanks! Being able to search the control panel is indeed one of the most useful features of Vista/7.
Also thx for the rundll shortcut.

Comment: This does not function for Admin users, right? I do not have that item.

Comment: awesome rundll shortcut man!

Comment: I could not find "environment" in either the start menu or Control Panel. But still the command line you posted worked well. Perhaps specific company restrictions were in place.

Comment: You can check with `set` on the commandline if the changes you made are active. If not restarting the commandline should be enough to activate your changes to the environment values.

Comment: It should be noted that `environment` should be replaced with localized versions, at least in Windows 7. For example, in Russian Windows 7 you need to search for `среды`.

Answer (score 32):

In addition to searching (as Johannes mentioned), "Change my environment variables" is listed under "Tasks" on the "User Accounts" control panel.

From the command line, you can create/modify persistent environment variables using the `setx` command, which is included in Windows Vista (and presumably Windows 7 too) and was part of the Windows Resource Kit Tools before that.

Comment: +1 for `setx`. This might be the answer to the somewhat related question I posted in the question.

Comment: Careful when using `setx` to modify existing variables that may contain environment variable references. Those will usually be expanded by then and can sometimes result in overly long environment variables. I once ended up with a `$Env:Path` that was too long and new entries just never worked.

Answer (score 10):

It is possible with the [Rapid Environment Editor](http://www.rapidee.com/en/about).

Comment: Nice little utility. The path error checking is a nice bonus, as is the possibility to edit the environment variables for any user on your computer - far more handy then to fiddle in the registry directly.

Answer (score 7):

In case you wish to edit an environment variable for a particular account but that variable is a part of system variables (which might be the case if you are setting path for a particular plugin) e.g. **Path** in Windows, you can achieve this by appending a semi-colon, if required, followed by `%variable_value%` like so:

```
Path=%Path%;c:\PathName\ForNewPlugin
```