# Command line app 'not recognized as internal or external command.'

Tags: windows-7, command-line, path, environment-variables

A few years back I made a couple of console command line apps which at the time worked with no issues. I'd place them in the window/system32 directory and be able to use them from the console prompt from anywhere on my system(Windows XP at that time).

Now I'm using Windows 7 64bit and this no longer works. I've tried placing my little console apps in `system32`, `syswow64`, Windows on down to the root of my c: drive, but windows continues to give me the same reply "'check' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

But! If I am within the same directory as the program it works as intended. I'm assuming there's either a 32bit/64bit app issue or OS internal security issue.

Can anyone point me in the right direction here? Do I need to create a directory in "Program Files(x86) and add that new directory to the PATH environment?

---

**Additional Note:**  This is a program I created.  It is not a batch file.  The program does work as it should when you are in the same directory as the program while you are in a console window.

Comment: Just to be sure we're on the same page: Are we talking about batch files here, or is it something else?

Comment: Hylltun can you edit your post and post the output of typing in `path` on the Command Prompt ?

Comment: Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Windows\System32>echo %PATH%
The system cannot find the file specified.

C:\Windows\System32>

Comment: Post your findings as an answer to your own question and accept it by clicking on the checkmark as soon as it's available. This will mark this question as answered.

Comment: @Daniel:  Ok, will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The environmental variable for PATH did not contain the windows directory nor either of the system directories.  I added all three paths to the PATH variable and now everything works as intended.

Thanks to everyone who replied with ideas, suggestions and questions.

Comment: You say "thanks to everyone ..." Well the best way to say thanks is really to up-vote the answer(s) that helped you (even though none was directly _the_ answer to your question). It is a good way to provide your own answer with the sollution and mark it as the answer as you did here, but if any other answers helped you on the way, you should give them an up-vote.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way, though, would be utilizing Windows's PATH environment variable. It ensures 100% the same functionality and doesn't involve you putting anything into the Windows directory. There's other questions directed at the same thing, the answers in [this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/25037/change-environment-variables-as-standard-user-windows-7/25038#25038) should put you up to that.

Comment: A fair answer, but if he's already dropped them in the Windows System32 folder, wouldn't it be recognised, since that's already in the default path?

Comment: Fair enough, it is puzzling.

Answer (score 1):

`.EXE` might be removed from `PATHEXT` in environment variable.

If this is the case add `.EXE` to `PATHEXT`.

Answer (score 0):

You're not saying whether you're running the program from a 32-bit command prompt or a 64-bit one. The 32-bit one will look in the SysWOW64 directory (it will see it as System32), and the 64-bit one will look in the System32 directory. (This should be a comment but I don't have enough rep to comment yet.)

If it's not clear, the 64-bit one is C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe, the 32-bit one is C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cmd.exe. If you're ever not sure what the bitness of an open prompt is, just run the 'set' command and look at the value of the 'ProgramFiles' environment variable. The 64-bit prompt should show it as C:\Program Files, the 32-bit one as C:\Program Files (x86).

Comment: I honestly didn't know there were separate sessions for the console window.

Comment: It's understandable, Windows only gives you one shortcut (in Start Menu > All Programs > Accessories), and that is for the 64-bit console. So you have to make your own shortcut to the 32-bit console.

Comment: Placed my program back into the Windows dir, tried both cmd.exe, the one in system32 and the one in syswow64, and same thing with both, program isn't recognized from the c: root, but if I cd to windows it all works fine.  This is really confounding.

Comment: @Garrett: What is the .exe called?  Have you tried renaming it to something else?

Comment: it's currently named check.exe but I'll rename it and see if that does the job.

Comment: Well snap!  that didn't work either and to find out, I can't even run notepad from the prompt either, nor any other exe in the windows directory unless I'm in that directory.

Comment: @Garrett: I want to comment on the above answer but don't have enough rep: Don't type 'echo %PATH%', just run the 'path' command.

Comment: @Chuck   C:\Windows\System32>PATH
PATH=<InstallFolder>;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files
 (x86)\Calibre2\;C:\Programs\hackety\hackety\..

Comment: @Chuck:  Since the environmental var for path did not contain the Windows dir and the two sys dirs, I added them to the PATH var and rebooted.  Now everything works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the part where you get "is not recognized as an internal or external command", take a look at this article:

[Cannot Ping getting 'ping is not recognized as an internal or external command'](http://jackofalltradesdeveloper.blogspot.com/2011/08/cannot-ping.html)

Answer (score 0):

1.>make Android folder in C drive (C:\Android)
2.>paste debug.keystore in Android Folder (C:\Android\debug.keystore)

keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Android\debug.keystore" | "C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.exe" base64

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Are you sure you're... answering the right question? This hardly seems to have any relevance.