# PostgreSQL on Windows: psql expects me to log in with my Windows account

Tags: windows-7, postgresql

I've just installed PostgreSQL 9.6 on Windows 7. I had to choose a password for the default user "postgres" during the install process.

Running pgAdmin4 after the install, I typed in my password for "postgres" and it was saved as expected.

But with the command line, the default user doesn't seem to be "postgres" but my Windows session user name, for which I don't have a PostgreSQL password (my Windows password doesn't work there). I can login with `psql -U postgres`, but how can I change the default user to be postgres?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `PGUSER` environment variable is considered when the `-U` option is not set.

So you may use a batch file essentially doing:

```
set PGUSER=postgres
psql
```

or set it permanently as mentioned in other questions such as [Change environment variables as standard user](https://superuser.com/questions/25037/change-environment-variables-as-standard-user).

In fact there are quite a few other variables corresponding to other connection properties that can be set similarly (see [Environment Variables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-envars.html) in the PostgreSQL documentation for the full list).

These variables are a feature of `libpq`, the DLL implementing the client-server interaction for most PostgreSQL applications, so they will work not just for `psql` but for all these applications.

Comment: This really helped me, been searching for a solution for the past hour, I just had to change the user env vars and it works now.

Comment: Thank you for this! Typing '-U postgres' every time was starting to be a nuisance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are in windows set the PGUSER to whichever user you want to use in environment variable.

```
export PGUSER=postgres
```

this worked for me perfectly