# How to change the user specific PATH on windows 10 HOME?

Tags: windows-10

On windows home we have several users (mostly family members). These users have different path requirements. Can they set their respective path ( without affecting others)? If that is not possible, how can the admin change the path for a particular user?

Comment: Do they have their own accounts? If not, why not?

Comment: @DavidPostill Yes, they have. Additionally,  I have admin and standard user account on the same machine. I could not figure out a when logged in as a standard user,  how to change my PATH.

Comment: Right click *My PC - Properties - Advanced System Settings* (at bottom of page) - *Environmental Variables* button.

Comment: @user1292580   For a standard user, clicking on Advanced System Settings  results in a pop up for admin password.

Comment: @qqqqq - Be sure you are modifying the user's PATH variable, under `user variables for ...` instead of PATH under `System variables`.  I have verified the [accepted answer](https://superuser.com/questions/25037/change-environment-variables-as-standard-user) works for the current version of Windows 10

Comment: @Ramhound Yes, the accepted answer works.

Comment: Your previous comment said it didn’t